# Local storage is used to store the token details when using AWS cognito with amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I curently implementing AWS cognito with Amplify for authentication in my react app.I have found once signed in, token in stored in the local storage. I think local storage is not ideal place to store the token details.

In Amplify documentation, they have told to use MyStorage to store the token details in secure way:

Security Tokens like IdToken or AccessToken are stored in localStorage for the browser and in AsyncStorage for React Native. If you want to store those tokens in a more secure place or you are using Amplify in server side, then you can provide your own storage object to store those tokens.

```
For example: 
class MyStorage {
    // the promise returned from sync function
    static syncPromise = null;
    // set item with the key
    static setItem(key: string, value: string): string;
    // get item with the key
    static getItem(key: string): string;
    // remove item with the key
    static removeItem(key: string): void;
    // clear out the storage
    static clear(): void;
    // If the storage operations are async(i.e AsyncStorage)
    // Then you need to sync those items into the memory in this method
    static sync(): Promise<void> {
        if (!MyStorage.syncPromise) {
            MyStorage.syncPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {});
        }
        return MyStorage.syncPromise;
    }
}

// tell Auth to use your storage object
Auth.configure({
    storage: MyStorage
});
```

I am not able to understand using MyStorage class to store the token.
Can anyone help me understand this better or give suggestion to store in any other secure place.

Comment: you can store in cookies by referring bellow docs or  in session storage `storage: sessionStorage`
refer https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource
set cookieStorage value will store tokens in cookie storage